# How to configure logback to skip logging messages from org.package.* with all levels below WARN?

Tags: java, logging, logback

How do I configure logback not to log messages from loggers in package org.package and it's subpackages unless their level is WARN or ERROR?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

And why isn't the following configuration not working for you?

```
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.package" level="WARN"/>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: BTW, what does "%d{ISO8601}" mean?

Comment: *ISO8601* is a standardized date format, see: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score 4):

`log.getLoggerContext().getLogger("package.name").setLevel(Level.WARN);`